# Error setting up systemd service for `code tunnel` with `code tunnel service install`

Tags: visual-studio-code, service

How do I fix this error for installing a systemd service for `code tunnel`?

```
$ code tunnel service install
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
[2023-05-10 17:46:44] info Successfully registered service...
[2023-05-10 17:46:44] info Successfully enabled unit files...
[2023-05-10 17:46:44] error error starting service: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit code-tunnel.service not found.
```

i have tried:

- above
- running as `sudo`
- running with `--verbose --log trace`, which doesn't give any additional info

my `uname -a`:

```
Linux <hostname> 4.19.0-24-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.282-1 (2023-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

i found a tentative "solution":

1. run `systemctl --user daemon-reload`
2. run `code tunnel service install`

this then creates a service file at `~/.vscode/cli/code-tunnel.service`

hat tip: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7778#issuecomment-1374515212